Amazon MQ as broker relay for Spring + Websocket + Stomp is not working
Im not able to connect to Amazon MQ(Active MQ) which i'm setting up as broker relay for web-socket connections over STOMP protocol.
Below are few of my configuration attempts
Environment:
Spring Boot Version: 2.7.17
Build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.17'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.7.9'
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.59.Final'
    implementation 'io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:1.0.12'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
group = 'com.dailycodebuffer'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'spring-websocket'
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.xxx.SpringBootApp'
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}


Amazon MQ setup
OpenWire -> ssl://abc.amazonaws.com:61617
STOMP -> stomp+ssl://abc.amazonaws.com:61614
application.properties
relay.host= abc.amazonaws.com
relay.port= 61617
relay.host.user= myuser
relay.host.password= my pwd
My first Websocket Configuration attempt is below
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Value("${relay.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${relay.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${relay.host.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${relay.host.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("wss-heartbeat-thread-");
        
        final ReactorNettyTcpClient<byte[]> client = new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                  .host(host)
                  .port(port)
                  .secure(), new StompReactorNettyCodec());

        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/")
                .setTcpClient(client)
                .setAutoStartup(true)
                .setClientLogin(user)
                .setClientPasscode(password)
                .setSystemLogin(user)
                .setSystemPasscode(password)
                .setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);     
    
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setPreservePublishOrder(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        final RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new AuthChannelInterceptor());
    }   
    
}

Error
2024-05-09 19:54:17.221  INFO 19660 --- [ent-scheduler-6] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: '\r' must be followed by '\n'
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: '\r' must be followed by '\n'
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.tryConsumeEndOfLine(StompDecoder.java:357) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.readCommand(StompDecoder.java:217) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decodeMessage(StompDecoder.java:143) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decode(StompDecoder.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decode(StompDecoder.java:88) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompReactorNettyCodec.decodeInternal(StompReactorNettyCodec.java:54) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.AbstractNioBufferReactorNettyCodec.decode(AbstractNioBufferReactorNettyCodec.java:41) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.ReactorNettyTcpClient$StompMessageDecoder.decode(ReactorNettyTcpClient.java:348) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[netty-all-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[netty-all-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]


Note : We also tried with STOMP port 61614 and that results in the following error.
2024-05-09 20:08:36.531  INFO 23700 --- [ient-loop-nio-3] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Failed to connect: handshake timed out after 10000ms

io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeTimeoutException: handshake timed out after 10000ms

My second Websocket Configuration attempt is below
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Value("${relay.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${relay.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${relay.host.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${relay.host.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("wss-heartbeat-thread-");
        
        final ReactorNettyTcpClient<byte[]> client = new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                  .host(host)
                  .port(61617)//Open-wire SSL port
                  .secure(), new StompReactorNettyCodec());

        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/")
                .setTcpClient(client)
                .setAutoStartup(true)
                .setRelayHost(host)
                .setRelayPort(61614) //STOMP port
                .setClientLogin(user)
                .setClientPasscode(password)
                .setSystemLogin(user)
                .setSystemPasscode(password)
                .setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);     
    
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setPreservePublishOrder(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        final RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

It also fails with
2024-05-09 20:14:11.863  INFO 1724 --- [ent-scheduler-8] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: '\r' must be followed by '\n'

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: '\r' must be followed by '\n'

My third Websocket Configuration attempt is below
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Value("${relay.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${relay.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${relay.host.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${relay.host.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("wss-heartbeat-thread-");
        
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/")
                .setAutoStartup(true)
                .setRelayHost(host)
                .setRelayPort(port) //Open-wire SSL port
                .setClientLogin(user)
                .setClientPasscode(password)
                .setSystemLogin(user)
                .setSystemPasscode(password)
                .setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);     
    
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setPreservePublishOrder(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        final RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new AuthChannelInterceptor());
    }   
    
}

In this case server starts successfully without any connection failure but when publishing message to the broker, im getting the following Message broker not active error.
2024-05-09 20:30:53.778 ERROR 30512 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Message broker not active. Consider subscribing to receive BrokerAvailabilityEvent's from an ApplicationListener Spring bean.] with root cause

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Message broker not active. Consider subscribing to receive BrokerAvailabilityEvent's from an ApplicationListener Spring bean.

It works locally using opensource ActiveMQ, only AWS MQ does not work.
Any help to get this working, would be much appreciated.

Replace section implement... by full content of build.gradle . And show your client (front-end source code).

Updated the full content of build.gradle and there is no client code

It is working fine now, the issue is STOMP port was not opened in our VPN config... thanks for your effort.
